# Implementing Pick type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

While trying to implement `Pick`, I was not sure why the type `WrongPick` gives bad result with an `|`.

```js
interface Todo {
  title: string
  description: string
  completed: boolean
}

type WrongPick<T, K> =  K extends keyof T ? {[P in K]: T[P]} : never

type wrong_result = WrongPick<Todo, 'title' | 'completed'>
// expected: { title: string ; completed: boolean }
// actual: { title: string } | { completed: boolean }

type CorrectPick<T, K extends keyof T> = {[P in K]: T[P]}

type correct_result = CorrectPick<Todo, 'title' | 'completed'>
// expected: { title: string ; completed: boolean }
// actual: { title: string ; completed: boolean }
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8BQyyYwYANhAFzIDOYUoA5ocphDQgwA4nojV0GIZkQToAtlwqRM1AEbp0FOCHwBffPjABPLigDqUPowAKwBAGsAPKgA0yANIA%20ZAF4iD5BAAekEJhpkCwhtdBg0ZAB%20PABtE2RQRwBdalQ4pLVkahAIADdoTR09ZAB3I2EAfSh2AFcyMDdkQ2MzSxssdHsAchJyCC7kAB9kLrFJaQhMLqd8AHpZr289BBlqXGJSCgF6JmQAbmQxqQhV5AUlCBVkDXnkRDAauDI1jb7toUZrobxDiWPT87KEDXQq6FAAYXQUGqK1a1jsjkWfgCQRCYTQLncuDiCWBDhSaHSGi0YN%200IgKyqtXqjUh5Nh5nhHW6vQoA2Goz%20EymM1uPmWp3WrKotB2wn2v3GJ0m8kUQJBt3uj2eP2F712ByO3NlFyuaiAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), `WrongPick<Todo, "title" | "completed">` actually expands to

```
("title" extends keyof T ? { [P in "title"]: Todo[P] } : never) | ("completed" extends keyof T ? { [P in "completed"]: Todo[P] } : never)
```

which simplifies to

```
{ title: string } | { completed: boolean }
```

As described in the above link to the documentation, you can "turn it off" by wrapping both sides in tuples:

```
type WrongPick<T, K> =  [K] extends [keyof T] ? { [P in K]: T[P] } : never
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpj9Bw)